# Recursive self query in Postgres/PADB without CTEs

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query, self-join

I am using PADB/Postgres which lacks recursive CTE's. I am trying to find a way to write a recursive self join using only regular joins/unions without recursive CTEs. What is the simplest way to do this?

I have a table like this:

```
PersonID | Initials | ParentID
1          CJ         NULL
2          EB         1
3          MB         1
4          SW         2
5          YT         NULL
6          IS         5
```

And I want to be able to get the records only related to a hierarchy starting with a specific person. So If I requested CJ's hierarchy by PersonID=1 I would get:

```
PersonID | Initials | ParentID
1          CJ         NULL
2          EB         1
3          MB         1
4          SW         2
```

And for EB's I'd get:

```
PersonID | Initials | ParentID
2          EB         1
4          SW         2
```

Comment: What's this PADB thing?

Comment: It's a product by actian (actian.com) that is supposed to handle big data. It is based on a version of Postgres sql but lacks some of its features.

Comment: instead of downvoting the answers without commenting, you should provide more information about the question you have. for example it is not specified at all that procedures or functions cannot be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution i can think of.

```
select * from t where personid = '1' --needs replacement with personid you run for
union
select * from t where personid in (select personid from t where parentid = '1')
or parentid in (select personid from t where parentid = '1')
```

The personid needs replacement with the person you need to see the hierarchy for.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1201/1

Comment: It covers 3 levels, but it won't work if you have a 4th level. For example if you add a 7th row in your table PersonID = 7, Inistials = 'AA', ParentID = 4